# Space above header in ddsmoothmenu

Tags: html, css, margin, spacing

i'm coding a website for some friends where i'm using ddsmoothmenu for dropdowns.. BUT now it there's a weird spacing between the header and top of the body, and it only appears on some pages.. It is very weird, and when checking it out through chromes developer options, i simple cannot find the reason for this spacing. BTW, i'm using 960 gs. The header gradient is body background image.

## EDIT

I now know WHAT the problem is. Everything in the head tag gets moved into body, on the pages with weird spacing. I have no idea why or how.

No weird spacing, exactly as it should be.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuQMK.jpg

Weird spacing!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5zQB.png

Here is the rendered source of one of the pages without the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.ico" />
    <title>Armilla - Forside</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" > 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=960">

<!--//////////////////// 
//Imports - JS and CSS//
/////////////////////--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css'  href='css/diapo.css' type='text/css' media='all'> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ddsmoothmenu.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ddsmoothmenu-v.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>

<!--[if !IE]><!--><script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.customized.min.js'></script><!--<![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/diapo.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/ddsmoothmenu.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

<!--///////
//Init JS//
////////-->
<script>

ddsmoothmenu.init({
mainmenuid: "menu", //menu DIV id
orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
//customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
});
</script>

</head> 

<body>
<div id="header" class="container_12">
<div id="logo" class="grid_5">
<a href="index.php">
<img src="img/logo.png" width="226" height="65"/>
</a>
</div>
<div id="nav" class="grid_7">
        <div id="menu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
            <ul>

                <li id="prodli"><a href="?p=products"><img src="img/produkter.png"/></a>
                    <ul style="z-index: 1;">
                    <li><a href="?p=prod$type="Armb�nd">Armb�nd</a></li><li><a href="?p=prod$type="Overlevelsesudstyr">Overlevelsesudstyr</a></li>                      </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="?p=armilla"><img src="img/armilla.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="?p=news"><img src="img/nyheder.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a id="lasta" href="?p=contact"><img src="img/kontakt.png"/></a></li>

            </ul>
            <br style="clear: left" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<section> 
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:960px; margin: auto auto; padding:0 20px;"> 
    <div class="pix_diapo">

        <div data-thumb="img/thumbs/megamind_07.jpg">

            <img src="img/slides/megamind_07.jpg"> 
            <div class="caption elemHover fromRight" style="bottom:65px; padding-bottom:5px; color:#ccc; text-transform:uppercase">
                Armilla
            </div>
            <div class="caption elemHover fromLeft" style="padding-top:5px;">
                Verdensklasses overlevelsesudstyr.Tjek vores nye <a href="?p=products">produkter</a> ud
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-thumb="img/thumbs/wall-e.jpg" data-time="7000">

            <img src="img/slides/wall-e.jpg">
            <div class="elemHover caption fromLeft" style="bottom:70px; width:auto; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
                You can also get the same effect as the caption with:
            </div>
            <div class="elemHover button fromTop" data-easing="easeOutExpo" style="left:388px; bottom:78px;">
                A button
            </div>
            <div class="elemHover button button2 fromBottom" data-easing="easeOutExpo" style="left:512px; bottom:78px;">
                Or two buttons
            </div>

            <div class="elemHover fadeIn" style="left:600px; bottom:auto; top:0; padding-top:50px; color:#ff0; font-size:13px; line-height:20px; width:auto; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; background:url(img/demo/arrow_caption.png) no-repeat 230px 30px">
                Or any other html element...<br>
                and you can decide the transition time of any slide
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-thumb="img/thumbs/up-official-trailer-fake.jpg">
            <iframe width="940" height="470" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qas5lWp7_R0?wmode=transparent&autoplay=1" data-fake="img/slides/up-official-trailer-fake.jpg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <div class="elemHover caption fromLeft elemToHide" style="bottom: 350px; width:auto; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; left:0">

                You can also display videos, but it requires a "fake image"... read the documentation please
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- #pix_diapo -->

</div>
</section> 
<script>
$(function(){
$(".pix_diapo").diapo();
});
</script>
<div id="footer" class="container_12">
<div style="text-align:center; color:#333333;" id="copyright" class="grid_12">
<p>Copyright 2012 &copy; - Armilla.dk - Alle rettigheder forbeholdt Armilla - <a href="?p=admin">Kontrolpanel</a> - <a href="?p=logout">Log ud</a>                                                                                      <br />Webdesign af <a href="http://www.doweb.dk" target="_blank">DoWEB</a></p>

</div>
</div>



</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Code? Link? Something to analyse?

Comment: I have no idea what to paste onto here, i don't kow whats causing it. But i will copy source of two pages that are affected, and one copy of a page that is not infected.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an **white-space** issue, where your html, css looks good on paper (in chrome developer), but isn't interpreted as it should be. To detect, if this is really the case, I would uglify my html and strip all whitespace in the html problem area.

If it turns out to be true, here are various [approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628050/ignore-whitespace-in-html) to this topic, even though most of 'em have small drawbacks (long uglified html lines, unnecessary comments, uncommon line breaks, ..).

Comment: The only weird thing is, that the content is autoloaded via php, and the header footer etc. is the same for all pages. Only the stuff after the header aka. logo and menu, is "hardcoded".. So i guess i should try looking at whitespace in my includes because it must be a problem with the includes themselves and not the standard template.

Answer (score 0):

After converting my index.php to UTF-8 Without BOM the whitespace issue dissappeared. So i'm a happy camper now! :D

I found this post about the same problem appearing in Wordpress when using Notepad++.
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/head-scriptslinks-showing-up-inside-body-tag