# ASP .NET MVC 3 + Razor View + Spaces Between Elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Consider the following Razor view - Let's call it VIEW-1 :

```
<h2>Index</h2>

@if (true)
{
    <img src="/Content/images/black_square.png" alt="Black Square" />
}

<img src="/Content/images/black_square.png" alt="Black Square" />
```

When I load the VIEW-1 into Internet Explorer 8 or Mozilla Firefox 9.0.1 the two "black square" images are separated by a space.
But I do not want the two images separated.

Now consider the following Razor view - Let's call it VIEW-2 :

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<img src="/Content/images/black_square.png" alt="Black Square" /><img src="/Content/images/black_square.png" alt="Black Square" />
```

When I load the VIEW-1 in Internet Explorer 8 or Mozilla Firefox 9.0.1 the two "black square" images are not separated by a space.

VIEW-1 and VIEW-2 are example views.
The "separated images" fact is a little problem in one of my ASP .NET MVC 3 project.
I can not write all my image elements on one line because some of them depend on condition statements and loop statements.

Is there a way to get image elements not separated by a space even if they are not written on the same line ?

Comment: you can use an helper method for generate img elements

Comment: Here's the same question on Stackoverflow, with an accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628050/ignore-whitespace-in-html

Answer (score 1):

You could try using CSS:

```
<div class="pictures">
    @if (true)
    {
        <img src="/Content/images/black_square.png" alt="Black Square" />
    }
    <img src="/Content/images/black_square.png" alt="Black Square" />
</div>
```

and then:

```
.pictures img {
    float: left;
}
```

​

Comment: +1. Use CSS to fine tune your image placement. Much easier than messing with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, Razor lets you do this:

```
<h2>Index</h2>

@if (true)
{
    <img src="/Content/images/black_square.png" alt="Black Square" />}<img src="/Content/images/black_square.png" alt="Black Square" />
```

... though whenever I do, I add an apologetic comment nearby explaining why I've done it.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this by inserting the images into a 1 row and 1 cell table:

```
<table>
@if (true)
{
    <img src="/Content/images/black_square.png" alt="Black Square" />
}

<img src="/Content/images/black_square.png" alt="Black Square" />
</table>
```

Comment: You forgot `tr` and `td`. There will still be a space though.

Comment: <table> are for representing tables. For alignment, there is CSS.