# vuejs router link and eslint rules

Tags: vue.js, eslint

If you install the vuejs eslint plugin and configure it to use the "strongly-recommended" ruleset, the linter will tell you to change the following code:

```html
<router-link class="my-link" :to="{ name: 'index' }">Home</router-link>
```

into this

```html
<router-link
  class="my-link"
  :to="{ name: 'index' }"
>
  Home
</router-link>
```

The problem is that when you do this, your `<a>` tag renders with a newline inside of the text causing the styling to look strange with an underline under nothing.

[This is the rule](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/multiline-html-element-content-newline.html) that causes the problem and you can definitely get around it by using configuration options and telling the rule to ignore `<router-link>` elements but then you end up with code styled just as strangely since other rules require the attributes to be on new lines:

```html
<router-link
  class="my-link"
  :to="{ name: 'index' }"
>Home</router-link>
```

Has anyone encountered this before?  Is there a way to just trim text inside anchor tags?  Am I missing something with the Vue Router configuration or ESLint configuration?

Here is a link to an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/rpf3/wex7dvpc/4/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196545/how-to-avoid-whitespace-anchor-underline-w-o-changing-coding-style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to use css here and make your links inline-block elements instead of the default inline, the white space will go away.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5cps4837/

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```