# get the exact width of an image with height:100%; using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I set the height of an image 100%, the width is calculated automatically in order to keep the image aspect ratio.
Most of the times the width of such image is not an integer but double (like 645.34).
`$("#myImg").width()` returns me always an integer.
How can I get the exact width of such an image using jquery?

Comment: The width() returned value is in "pixel". I don't see how your image could have a non-integer width value.

Comment: @koopajah: float value is non-integer value. When you put am image 100% height for example, the img width will not be integer. Maybe this will interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655762/i-need-to-add-one-pixel-to-parent-div

Comment: I know a float is not an integer. What I'm saying is that you image will never have a float width or a float height. They are based on pixels, and you can not have an image with a width of 100 and a half pixels. It will always be an integer

Answer (score 1):

The actual applied width will *always* be equated to an integer value of pixels by the browser. There is no renderable half-pixel. We can specify `22.5px` etc, but it will be rounded to the nearest integer by the browser. Some browsers may however anti-alias the edge pixels to simulate half-pixels, still the applied width/height value will *always* be an integer.

Comment: So if I have 10 images one after another and I want them to be displayed one by one in one line with no spaces between, how can I calculate the width of all the images? Isn't it possible?

Comment: You can use `.width()` on each image and sum them. Also note that you can use `.outerWidth()` to control whether you want the calculated width to include margins (if any) as well.

Comment: as yo can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655762/i-need-to-add-one-pixel-to-parent-div summing the widths is not working and is not a solution..