# Correct HTML mark-up syntax? (to remove whitespace between inline-block elements)

Tags: html, css, syntax, html-parsing

When html code is not 'beautified', it looks like

```
<div><img src="img1.jpg"/><img src="img2.jpg"/></div>
```

And then these pictures rendered as

```
|=||=| //no gap between
```

But after beautifier http://ctrlq.org/beautifier/

```
<div>
    <img src="img1.jpg"/>
    <img src="img2.jpg"/>
 </div>
```

They are rendered like this

```
|=| |=| // gap (space) between
```

So, same code rendered differently. I want to figure how to do correct syntax for html inlined elements (and html at all)?

(inlined could be even 'block' elements), so I don't know, how to write code that could be human readable and rendered correctly (without gaps between inlined elements at least).

Any suggestions? =)

Comment: This seems like a bug in the beautifier. It shouldn't make changes that can have an effect on rendering.

Comment: @Barmar: That's impossible to determine; the beautifier has to make guesses sometimes. (For example, if a stylesheet applied `white-space: pre` to anything, it would make most things unchangeable, and there's no easy way of telling when that would apply.)

Comment: Not to mention [`::before` and `::after` and whitespace](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/4TZV3/)...

Comment: @minitech: seems like there a gap =)

Comment: @EL: Oh, there is - the point is to illustrate that it's impossible to beautify HTML and be sure that no layout will change. (Note the trailing spaces inside each `<div>` - if an `::after` element is added, they matter, but otherwise, it's ignored [note the border].)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several options to displaying inline-block elements in a easily read manner, none of which are perfect.

**Option 1**: Left Floats

Here is a tutorial on Floats in general: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/
It is highly recommended for all front end developers to be well versed in this subject.

**Option 2**: Nested comments (already posted)

```
<div>
    <img src="img1.jpg"/><!-- 
 --><img src="img2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**Option 3 (potentially in the future):** `text-space-collapse: discard;` (previously `white-space-collapse: discard;`)

The CSS property `white-space-collapse` is not recommended because of poor browser adoption (see comment below). It appears this property is no longer a part of the text decoration specification. I have also found reference to `text-space-collapse` as being considered for the future.

**Option 4**: Don't try

You can't expect to have beautiful code when using display:inline-block. It is my opinion that your use of inline-block and desire of beautiful code are mutually exclusive without use of float:left.

**Option 5**: Add `font-size: 0` to a parent element. Apparently this doesn't work with Safari, so the solution is of similar value to `white-space-collapse: discard;`.

Comment: div's style="white-space-collapse:discard;" (tried preserve/collapse/preserve-breaks/discard) had no effect (in opera 12)

Comment: Thanks, this is partially why its not recommended to use that option. Option 4 and Option 1 are my personal choices.

Comment: I'm curious is there a way to display 'beautified source html code' that after it copied to clipboard it is 'not beautified'? But I think that is particular question fo another subject.

Comment: Yeah, [it was gone once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements#comment16711500_5078350). (Is it back?)

Comment: I've had this same thought (out of personal desperation). One day hopefully an IDE will provide this kind of editing, but as far as I know, it doesn't currently exist.

Comment: @ktamlyn: Ok. I'll try to make a history =)

Comment: Does an implementation exist for either `white-space-collapse`, or `text-space-collapse`? Where are they being proposed? This information should be in your answer.

Comment: @Sime Vidas, I don't know more than I have stated. Both properties appear to be absent in current specification documents I am aware of. CSS Text Decoration Module Level 3 (http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/) and CSS Text Module Level 3 (http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-text/). This information comes from your question linked to above by minitech.

Comment: @ktamlyn `white-space-collapse` has been dropped, and it's not implemented anywhere, so there's no reason to mention it. `text-space-collapse` is proposed in a [preliminary draft of Text Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css4-text/#white-space-collapsing) (not published as TR yet). That draft itself is not ready for implementations. Therefore, I wouldn't list these properties as an option, as they aren't, but have a note at the bottom with info about this potentially upcoming property.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I agree it would have been better to write it out your way but I came to learn of these facts after my original post, so I can't change the list's order now. But I edited the answer considering your input.

Comment: `font-size: 0;` plus `line-height: 0;` to a parent element DOES WORK for Safari 7. Of course, you have to reset the font size and line height for child elements.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your browser, it may be rendered as a space. You can try this:

```
<div>
    <img src="img1.jpg"/><!-- 
 --><img src="img2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

`<!--` is a comment tag that will be ignored by browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm going to be hated for saying this. Buuuuut....

If you want to position your img's precisely next to one another AND have "beautified" code you need to use a table.

`Cue screaming`

With css you can do whatever you want with 2 img in a div except position them precisely like a table.

This code....

```
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="img1.jpg"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="img2.jpg"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

will get you the result you desire but the question is, can you live with yourself afterwards?

Relevent fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/t4Krs/

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but it's prettier than the comment trick in my opinion:

```
<div>
  <
   img src="img1.jpg"/><
   img src="img2.jpg"
  >
</div>
```