# PHP adds extra whitespace on require

Tags: php, whitespace, require-once

Consider the following code:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<?php
  require_once('/components/search.php');
  require_once('/components/categories.php');
?>
</div>
```

`search.php` and `category.php` are essentially the same structure - a div container with some specific contents. Nothing special here, pure HTML:

```
<div class="component">
<!-- blah -->
</div>
```

However, when inserted with `require_once` (or `require` / `include` etc), PHP adds whitespace above each element, pushing it down, identifiable as an empty text node in Chrome's Inspect Element tool (the whitespace disappears when this node is deleted)

Deleting all unnecessary whitespace from the sidebar script (making it a single line of code) doesn't fix it. And if I just replace the `require_once` lines with the contents of the components, the whitespace doesn't appear. So not sure why PHP is adding it on require. Any ideas?

**Update**

This one's still proving to be a weird one. I agree now that `require_once` does not seem to be the root cause as such. I decided to ignore the problem for a while and hope it would go away after I'd worked on it further. Alas, it remains, so I did bit more investigating. Checking the page source in the browser confirms that the code in question is indeed returned as a single long unbroken line http://pastebin.com/dtp7QNbs - there's no whitespace or carriage return between any of the tags, yet space appears in the browser - identifiable in the Inspect Element tool as empty lines between each `<div class="component">`

Does this help shed any more light on the issue?

Comment: I highly doubt the `require_once` is adding white space. You should look at the files that are being included and see if there is anything trailing at the end.

Comment: Place the `require` statements in a single line: `<?php   require_once('/components/search.php');   require_once('/components/categories.php'); ?>` and remove any trailing space after the closing PHP tag.

Comment: Remove any trailing ?> at the end of each of your included files

Comment: @njk the contents of the included are exactly as pasted - right down to the `<!--blah-->` (I wanted to check to see if the contents were somehow adding it).
@BenM did that (see third-to-bottom line). Whitespace still exists
@MarkBaker `search.php` and `categories.php` are currently pure HTML, so there are no ?> to remove

Comment: Then this is a styling issue, not a `PHP` issue.

Comment: The whitespace is identifiable as an actual dom element in the inspector, an extra `""` text node above each component. This isn't a styling issue (assuming you mean an errant CSS rule), and I have no CSS rules that add HTML. This site is also currently devoid of Javascript. I went back to my text editor and removed all whitespace from all files (all three files are now a single line each), the whitespace still occurs

Comment: I think njk is suggesting that you use CSS to suppress the effect of the whitespace, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628050/ignore-whitespace-in-html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and verified Kai's solution to change the format to ANSI but also found that "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" also works. 
This comes up as the default format for new Notepad++ PHP files so one less conversion step.

It seems that use of the byte order mark file header in UTF-8 is not generally recommended. I verified that my installation of VS2010 was adding BOM when saving PHP files.

The following stackoverflow article explains nicely where the extra whitespace got inserted.

[What's different between utf-8 and utf-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926)

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved! This took forever to figure out. The short answer is that my php files were UTF-8 encoded. Changing this in Notepad++ to ANSI fixed it.

I only found the real cause of the problem by doing a character-by-character comparison of the output HTML - one output from where 'require_once' was used and one where the code was manually pasted in place.

In a *visual* comparison of the output, both appeared identical - same length, no extra/different characters. But when pushed through `preg_split('//', $string)`, and looped through character by character, 3 extra "invisible" characters were revealed at the start of each `require_once` insert point. I idenitified these as the ASCII characters `&#239;`, `&#187;` and `&#191;` (a double-dotted i, a right chevron and an upside-down question mark).

Changed the encoding to ANSI (I discovered this as the cause when I recreated one of the scripts in Notepad word-for-word and it did not suffer the same issue), and the extra lines have gone.

Answer (score 2):

The extra characters are the BOM (Byte Order Mark). So converting to UTF-8 without BOM was the real trick here. More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 2):

some time it happened because of white space after `?>` on the class file, also or before `<?php`

Comment: Yes you are correct, I don't know why someone marked you down. I have spent a good while wondering where white space was coming from for a part of my project. I had sent headers and somewhere whitespace was breaking it. Turns out there were spaces after the closing ?> in a file I was including - even the docs hint at this. So thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to save PHP file as **UTF-8 without mark symbols** in Programmer's Notepad editor using:

1. File -> Encoding -> UTF-8 No Mark
2. File -> Save

After that `require` command will include PHP script without adding whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

First, put `<?php` on the same line as the DIV:

```
<div id="sidebar"><?php
```

This gets rid of the whitespace before `search.php`.

Then make sure that `search.php` has no newline at the end, that's causing the whitespace between `search.php` and `categories.php`. Some text editors add a trailing newline by default, you may need to override this.

I just tried this, the output of `php main.php` is:

```
<div id="sidebar"><div class="component">
<!-- search.php -->
</div><div class="component">
<!-- categories.php -->
</div></div>
```

Comment: Tried this, (see last paragraph). There isn't any trailing whitespace so far as I can tell - files are written in Notepad++, checked them in Notepad, there's no extra space to be found

Comment: I'm on a Mac, I used Emacs, and set `require-final-newline` to nil before writing the file. Don't know how to do this in Notepad++.