# Trying to put li tags in the right order

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to float li tags to the right in the order Information, Work and Contact, however when I float them they change the order to what you see on [this link](http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/test_nav/)

I can fix this by giving the UL a width and then floating the UL right and then floating the LI left but I need the UL tag to be the full width of the Nav div (its parent) for it to be responsive.

HTML:

```
    <header>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-medium.png" alt="Madaxe Designs Web      Development &amp; IT Service" class="logo"></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="info flex" title="Information"></a></li>
                <li><a class="work flex" title="Work" href="portfolio.html"></a></li>                       
                <li><a class="contact flex" title="Contact"></a></li>               
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
nav { 
    width: 57.9%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
header nav ul{ 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    float: right; 
}               
header nav li{ 
    width: 22.3%; 
    height: 112px; 
    float: right;    
    padding-left: 5px;
}
header nav li a { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: That is the correct behavior for float:right. As you correctly noted, you can float them left in a right-floated container. But Is it not possible to just reorder the li list?

Comment: I thought that re-ordering the list would be an option but when I go to shrink the browser and the buttons go underneath one another they look daft in that order. As obviously on the link provided they are in the right order when the browser is shrunk down.

Comment: Just FYI, you should preload the hover state images. There is a delay before the browser caches them, for users that haven't visited your page before.

Comment: If you're using HTML5 tags like `nav` then you should be using `inline-block` and not floats for your layout.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that on the main site using AJAX but this is only messing about really. Why wouldn't I use floats and use Inline-block instead?

Comment: @Maximus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/drawback-of-css-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft/15177860#15177860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go

```
header nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
header nav li {
    width: 22.3%;
    height: 112px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* only for ie7 support */
    zoom: 1;          /* only for ie7 support */
}
```

**Brief explanation:**
What I did is remove all the floated elements, because in your case its was unnecessary and inline-block is way better, here is a explanation
[**explanation why its better**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/drawback-of-css-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft/15177860#15177860)

Then I align the whole content to the right with `text-align:right;`

**About the star hack:**
This is a necessary evil for support IE7, because he doesn't support `display:inline-block` so to accomplish a inline-block effect on IE7 you should use

```
display: inline;
zoom: 1;
```

But if you add `display:inline` he will override the `display: inline-block` for browsers that support it, that is why we use what is call *star hack* to target only IE7

Comment: Legend this seems to be working fine. Could you explain what you have done for others and myself in the future please?

Comment: I would not recommend the star hack, but instead changing the `li` elements to be an element that is inline by default, because the star hack is not valid CSS.

Comment: Like i said if he doesn't need support ie7 he doenst need this two lines,

Comment: I have set a block for IE so if it can't go any smaller than 940px on any ie browser lower than 8. Thanks for this. Really useful read.

Comment: `inline-block` is great, but sometimes when trying to achieve layout with it, you get issues because it utilizes whitespace. I would recommend adding `font-size: 0` to the `<ul>` and then setting the correct font-size on the `<li>`'s.

Comment: The problem with `font-size:0` is if you are using em that can be an issue, since ems cascade the children would also have zero font size. Another way to resolve the whitespace http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: You would just use the CSS `white-space` property to remove whitespace.

Comment: property `white-space` has nothing to do with the space between inline-block elements