# Divs are not appearing next to each other

Tags: css, html

I am building a backend for a website and I got a strange behavior of display `table`/`cell`/`row`

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5G9nJ/

html

```
<div id="App">
            <div id="AppFrame">
                <div id="AppMenu">
                    <div id="AppMenuContent">test</div>
                    <div id="AppMenuLog">test</div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
 html, body{
                height: 100%;
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;

                background-color: #ebebeb;
                font-family:Helvetica;
            }
            #App{
                height: 100%;
                display: table;
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
            }
            #AppFrame{
                display: table-row;
                height: 100%;
                margin-top: 0px;
            }
            #AppMenu{
                height: 100%;
                width: 300px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                display: table-cell;               
            }
            #AppMenuContent{
                max-width: 65px;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: red;
            }
            #AppMenuLog{
                margin-left: 65px;
                width: 200px;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #999999;               
            }
            #AppDisplay{
                display: table-cell;
                height: 100%;
            }
```

The problem is that, the div "AppMenuLog" will not appear next to the div "AppMenuContent"! I've tried to set the both divs to blocks, changed the width and heights but nothing solves this, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with the `table` structure check this

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/5G9nJ/8/)

`display:table-cell;` needs to be added to `#AppMenuLog` and `#AppMenuContent`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `display: inline-block` to `#AppMenuContent` and `#AppMenuLog`.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CqfgV/).

This is a lot better and easier than using `float: left`; see the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/drawback-of-css-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft).

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5G9nJ/6/)**

You need to add `float:left` to div #AppMenuContent

```
#AppMenuContent {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 65px;
}
```

Comment: I'd avoid using `float` to get divs inline, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/drawback-of-css-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft

Comment: @KaiFeller I disagree, float is a suitable way to get `div`s inline.

Comment: It's not preferable, it will case positioning issues as they are not in the page flow.

Comment: Seconding Kai's suggestion. `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;` is probably what he wants here. Floating block-level elements can cause extra problems requiring a clearfix hack to solve.

Comment: @KaiFeller You can wrap them in a container if needed. I haven't really look into this question so you could be right in saying for this situation it would not be wise to use it. I'm more talking overall there is no problem using float, I use it all the time and have no problems with it (again, you do need to know when to use it)

Comment: Read the link in my first comment, you can use float, but it is preferable and will cause less disruption and problems if you use inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

Next time try to search harder an answer. On this is are a lot of questions similar with your. You need to use `float:left;`

Here you find your solution http://jsfiddle.net/5G9nJ/5/

Comment: I'd avoid using `float` to get divs inline, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/drawback-of-css-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft

Comment: Divs have display:block by default with a reason. In my opinion to set a div as inline-block is a big mistake...

Comment: Yeah and there is `display: inline-block` for a reason, to display blocks inline...if you use the float property there will be positioning issues as they are not in the page flow.

Comment: And why do you thing it will pe positioning issues? I'm working for a lot of time with float and all goes perfect. If you can tell what is the problem with my demo I'll give you right. But until then... in my opinion display: inline-block is pointless...

Comment: Read the link I posted in my first comment, you might learn something.

Comment: Frankly speaking I'll try to use display:inline-block but I've my doubts. I'm affraid i'm "a lost cause" and I got used to much with float. From my point of view working with float is pretty easy is you know to clear it after. But I'll try this option to. Good chat @Kai :)

Comment: Yup, try to use `inline-block` - it'll make your life a lot easier!