# 3 column footer background color

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to change the background color of a footer. I tried making another div around it which worked but no matter what the background-color didn't budge. I must be overlooking something obvious!

This is what I have right now: http://jsfiddle.net/x5yvm50r/

And the code:

```
<div class="floatleft">
<h3>Heading</h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
</div>
<div class="floatleft">
<h3>Heading</h3>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/N23RQo5.png">
</div>
<div class="floatleft">
<h3>Heading</h3>
social icons
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

.floatleft {float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0; width: 400px;}
.clear {clear:both}
```

If anyone has any idea, I'd really appreciate pointing me in the right direction! This is more or less what I'm hoping for it to look like eventually [image]

Thanks! :)

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/x5yvm50r/1/) what you want???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you should wrap the content in a seperate block level element (i.e. div or footer). Here is the updated fiddle, using a block level element with id="wrapper": http://jsfiddle.net/df1zjwmb/1/

```
<footer id="wrapper">
   <div class="floatleft">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a>
            </li>
    </div>
    <div class="floatleft">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/N23RQo5.png">
    </div>
    <div class="floatleft">
         <h3>Heading</h3>
        social icons
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</footer>
```

And the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Clearing floated elements means that elements below the clear will be reset, but does not turn the floated elements into a block itself. To solve the problem requires adding a wrapper div, which creates a block level element that you can apply a background color to. Or you could use something other than floats, like inline blocks.

Here is more information: [Advantages of using display:inline-block vs float:left in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/drawback-of-css-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft)

Answer (score 1):

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/x5yvm50r/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="floatleft footcontainer">
    <div class="floatleft">

<h3>Heading</h3>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a>
            </li>
    </div>
    <div class="floatleft">

<h3>Heading</h3>

        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/N23RQo5.png">
    </div>
    <div class="floatleft">

<h3>Heading</h3>
social icons</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.floatleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 400px;
}
.clear {
    clear:both
}
.footcontainer {
    background-color:lightblue;
    float:left;
}
```

I've added a div which holds the 3 divs and gave it the background color and the float property.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/5s4w19zy/

I wrapped the three floated divs in a container div (footer) and then floated them inside of that.

```
<footer>
    <div>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/N23RQo5.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        social icons
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</footer>
```

---

```
footer
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    overflow: hidden;
}

footer div
{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 33.333333%;
    height: 150px;
}

.clear {clear:both}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 offers semantic markup tags, and since you need a wrapper for your footer (allowing a parent element to have a the background-color property of your choosing), `<footer>` tag sounds like the way to go:

```
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="floatleft">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://">Link 1</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="floatleft">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/N23RQo5.png">
    </div>
    <div class="floatleft">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    social icons
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</footer>
```

`#footer { background-color:#asYouLikeIt; }`

Comment: The idea of the semantic tags is that you don't need to give it an id of what it is

Comment: "...yes...?", he said warily.

Answer (score 0):

I have used flex box:

check this : http://jsfiddle.net/x5yvm50r/9/

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <section class="left">l</section>
    <section class="center">c</section>
    <section class="right">r</section>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer{
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
}
footer section{
    flex:1;
}
```