# Links on New Line

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have the following:

**HTML**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
            <title>Result</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div>
            <a href= https://google.com>Google</a>
            <a href= https://google.com>Google</a>
            <a href= https://google.com>Google</a>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
    a:hover{
        text-decoration: none
    }
    a:first-child{
        color: #CDBE70
    }
    a:nth-child(3){
        color: #FFC125
}
```

I just started learning HTML and I have a problem. What I have above displays 3 links to google but they are all on the same line. I want each of the links to be on a new line. I tried using `<p>` and changed all the a's to p's in the CSS code but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Use float:left; clear:left to your anchor tag in CSS

Comment: By the looks of it you probably want to use `ul` and `li`s instead.

Answer (score 7):

If the links are semantically in a list, you should reproduce that in the markup as well:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you don't want to have bullets in front of the links, you can remove them with CSS `list-style-type: none;` on either the `ul` or the `li`s.

Answer (score 3):

CSS:
Add display: table in your  tag

```
a{display: table;}
```

Comment: It works, I did `link.style.display = 'table'`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with CSS by using `float:left;` and `clear:left;`

```
a {
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain both props which create a new line. I did `let link = document.createElement('a');link.textContent = 'youtube';link.style.float = 'left';link.style.clear = 'left'` and no new line created.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<br/>` tag to break the row.

```
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a><br/>
```

But with this solution you'll have to modify the css, as the next `<a>` is no longer a child. Instead you can use [nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) and [first-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp):

```
a:hover { text-decoration: none }
a:nth-of-type(3) { color: #FFC125 }
a:first-of-type { color: #CDBE70 }
```

This will assure that only `<a>` tags are part of the selectors.

or you can put each link in it's own `<div>`:

```
<div class="menu"><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></div>
<div class="menu"><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></div>
<div class="menu"><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></div>
a:hover { text-decoration: none }
div.menu:nth-child(3) a { color: #FFC125 }
div.menu:first-child a { color: #CDBE70 }
```

Comment: When I do <br/>, the css messes up. Instead of the last link being golden yellow it makes the second link golden yellow and the last link will be blue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using break to give a line break between the three links like this;   

<div>
        <a href= https://google.com>Google</a><br/>
        <a href= https://google.com>Google</a><br/>
        <a href= https://google.com>Google</a><br/>
</div>
```

- `<br>` produces a line break in text.
- Line break tag can be placed in other HTMl elements like
  paragraphs, lists, tables and headings
- Use line break tag for minor formatting issues. For larger issues
  use tables and align attribute.
- Line break tag does not require a closing tag.
- For increasing the gap between the lines of text use CSS margin property.

  • margin-bottom: 0
  • margin-left: 0
  • margin-right: 0
  • margin-top: 0

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bWTwL/1349/)

```
a{ 
    display:block; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none
}
a:first-child{
    color: #CDBE70
}
a:nth-child(3){
    color: #FFC125
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `<br/>` or `<p>` tag after each of your link ,it will be displayed on new line. :)

Answer (score 0):

see this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9e3a2kej/)

and css

```
<style>     
  div a{
   display:list-item;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to break into a new line, you should look to use the `display: block;` declaration in your css.

[Here's a few reasons as to why to use display instead of float](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15177860/3436942).

Floating elements is all well and good, but can become messy due to the 'floated element' coming out of the DOM, which makes it harder to position other elements.

`a` elements default to `display:inline`, meaning multiple a tags appear in a single line. By changing them to `display:block;` means that only one will be in a row at a time (i.e. what you are looking for).

A quick demo would be something like:

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none
}
a:first-child {
  color: #CDBE70
}
a:nth-child(3) {
  color: #FFC125
}
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <title>Result</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do what Twitter's Bootstrap does all over the place and surround your elements with divs with proper classes. What I would do is:

CSS

```
.anchors a:hover{
        text-decoration: none
    }
    .anchors div:first-child a{
        color: #CDBE70
    }
    .anchors div:nth-child(3) a{
        color: #FFC125
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="anchors">
    <div>
        <a href= https://google.com>Google</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href= https://google.com>Google</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href= https://google.com>Google</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I surrounded a tags with divs to make the a tags selectable by their indexes in css. In order to access them in the dom, defined a wrapper div and named its class **anchors**. I am first selecting the wrapper div (.anchors) and accessing it's child divs with indexes and then their anchors.

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bWTwL/1349/).