# Block level elements behavior

Tags: html, css

Here is the following HTML/CSS.

```css
li {
  float: left;
  background-color: #BD4932;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  color: #FFFAD5;
}
```

```html
<h1>Dynamic horizontal centering</h1>
<h2>With <span class="orange">display:table</span></h2>
<nav role='navigation' class="nav-table">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Results: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVeBGv

My understanding is that block level elements force following elements to a new line. Why doesn't the `display: block;` put the list items in new line?

Comment: It's because of the _float: left;_. For some more info read [this stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/advantages-of-using-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft-in-css).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, block level elements by default take 100% width of their parent. The won't push the next element in a new line. Your anchors parent (the list-item) is floated to the left, meaning that it will only be as width as it's content.

If you want the anchors (and list-items) to move to the next line, then remove the `float: left` from the `li`

```css
li {
  /*float: left;*/
  background-color: #BD4932;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  color: #FFFAD5;
}
```

```html
<h1>Dynamic horizontal centering</h1>
<h2>With <span class="orange">display:table</span></h2>
<nav role='navigation' class="nav-table">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

or add `clear: both` to it:

```css
li {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #BD4932;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  color: #FFFAD5;
}
```

```html
<h1>Dynamic horizontal centering</h1>
<h2>With <span class="orange">display:table</span></h2>
<nav role='navigation' class="nav-table">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `float: left`.

`display: block` is redundant if you've specified float: left (or right).

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you asked for. (Take off the `float:left;`)

```
ul {
     list-style: none;    
   }

li {
      background-color: #BD4932;
    }

    li a {
      display: block;
      padding: .5em 1em;
      color: #FFFAD5;
    }

    <h1>Dynamic horizontal centering</h1>
    <h2>With <span class="orange">display:table</span></h2>
    <nav role='navigation' class="nav-table">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```