# Tab content not showing up

Tags: html, css

I am creating tabs using CSS only. The way it works is, there are 3 radio buttons, and a label for each radio button. The tab contents are set to `display: none`. When a tab gets selected, then that tab contents become `display: block`

Since there were white spaces separating the `labels` (tabs) I added a `div` around the `input/label` elements and used the [Flexbox technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27459795/4861207).

Now that I added the `div` around the `inputs/labels`, the tab contents never show, they never become `display: block`.

How can I make the tab contents show when a tab gets selected?

Here's the relevant code:

```
.tab1:checked ~ .tab1,
.tab2:checked ~ .tab2,
.tab3:checked ~ .tab3 {
  display: block;
}
```

**Working, but with white space**
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzvg8x9r/)

```css
.tab {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px green solid;
}
.tabContent,
input {
  display: none;
}
.tab1:checked ~ .tab1,
.tab2:checked ~ .tab2,
.tab3:checked ~ .tab3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="overallDiv">
  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab1" checked="checked" />
  <label for="rad1" class="tab">Fisrt Tab</label>

  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab2" />
  <label for="rad2" class="tab">Second Tab</label>

  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad3" class="tab3" />
  <label for="rad3" class="tab">Third Tab</label>

  <div class="tabContent tab1" id="first">
    First Tab
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent tab2" id="second">
    Second Tab
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent tab3" id="third">
    Third Tab
  </div>
</div>
```

**Not Working, but now white spaces**
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1jdL3594/)

```css
.tab {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px green solid;
}
.tabContent,
input {
  display: none;
}
.tab1:checked ~ .tab1,
.tab2:checked ~ .tab2,
.tab3:checked ~ .tab3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="overallDiv">
  <div id="tabWrapper" style="display: flex;">
    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="rad1" class="tab">Fisrt Tab</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab2" />
    <label for="rad2" class="tab">Second Tab</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad3" class="tab3" />
    <label for="rad3" class="tab">Third Tab</label>
  </div>

  <div class="tabContent tab1" id="first">
    First Tab
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent tab2" id="second">
    Second Tab
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent tab3" id="third">
    Third Tab
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `float: left` to your `.tab` style

Comment: `float` isn't meant for layout. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15177860/4861207 If you don't want to read the whole thing, just read the part about float.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew. I posted an answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As inline element have a space margin, your div becomes a little bigger than 33% and therefore doesn't fit in 1 row.

To your *Working, but with white space* sample I <strike>added `margin-right: -4px;`</strike> re-ordered your html a little to take that space out, but this can be done using other hacks, floats and flex. (for floats/flex, see below)

The trick in this case is to make the inline elements stop and start tag to be on the same line like this: `</label><label`

Note: These margin space issues has already been solved before

- [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)
- [Why is there an unexplainable gap between these inline-block div elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements)

```css
.tab {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px green solid;
}
.tabContent,
input {
  display: none;
}
.tab1:checked ~ .tab1,
.tab2:checked ~ .tab2,
.tab3:checked ~ .tab3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="overallDiv">
  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab1" checked="checked" />
  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab2" />
  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad3" class="tab3" />
  <label for="rad1" class="tab">First Tab
  </label><label for="rad2" class="tab">Second Tab
  </label><label for="rad3" class="tab">Third Tab
  </label>

  <div class="tabContent tab1" id="first">
    First Tab
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent tab2" id="second">
    Second Tab
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent tab3" id="third">
    Third Tab
  </div>
</div>
```

As requested a flex version.

```css
#overallDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tab {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px green solid;
}
.tabContent,
input {
  display: none;
}
.tabContent {
  width: 100%;
}
.tab1:checked ~ .tab1,
.tab2:checked ~ .tab2,
.tab3:checked ~ .tab3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="overallDiv">
    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="rad1" class="tab">Fisrt Tab</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab2" />
    <label for="rad2" class="tab">Second Tab</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad3" class="tab3" />
    <label for="rad3" class="tab">Third Tab</label>

  <div class="tabContent tab1" id="first">
    First Tab
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent tab2" id="second">
    Second Tab
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent tab3" id="third">
    Third Tab
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit

Here is a "floats" version

```css
#overallDiv {
  clear: left;
}
.tab {
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px green solid;
}
.tabContent,
input {
  display: none;
}
.tab1:checked ~ .tab1,
.tab2:checked ~ .tab2,
.tab3:checked ~ .tab3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="overallDiv">
  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab1" checked="checked" />
  <label for="rad1" class="tab">First Tab</label>
  
  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab2" />
  <label for="rad2" class="tab">Second Tab</label>
  
  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad3" class="tab3" />
  <label for="rad3" class="tab">Third Tab</label>

  <div class="tabContent tab1" id="first">
    First Tab
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent tab2" id="second">
    Second Tab
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent tab3" id="third">
    Third Tab
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the flex method the best. Is there a way doing that using flex?

Comment: @Jessica Added a flex version to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! The flexbox version is causing me more problems, so I think I'll just go with the margin technique. Will it always be `-4px`? (In different browsers. etc) Is it safe to rely on that?

Comment: @Jessica I updated my answer (first sample) with another and more safer way than the margin trick. The margin trick though, is also safe, safer than the `font-size: 0` trick, but one might need to adjust the negative margin value a little based on the font size used.

Comment: @Jessica Btw, if you want flex, add a new question with the problems you got and post me a comment here and I might be able to assist with that (or someone before me).

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it!

Comment: How is the margin trick safer than `font-size: 0`? Take a look at solution 3 in the link I posted in my answer. It says to **avoid** the margin trick at all costs.

Comment: @Anthony The `font-size: 0` trick has issues on some Andriod versions which margin trick hasn't. **But** you are very right, all those tricks should be avoided at all costs and therefore I changed my answer earlier to a better solution.

Comment: @Anthony As the question kind of already had a solution (posted links in my anser) which wasn't obvious based on the title, I also made my answer a community wiki to not get any vote credits in the future.

Comment: I don't really care about vote credits. I am here to learn. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of methods to remove whitespace. Here's a good article on a couple of methods https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block. If you don't want your html to become messy you could add a `font-size` of **0** to the parent element, then if you have text in the child elements add a `font-size` to them. Your CSS would look like this:

parent element:

```
#overallDiv {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

child elements:

```
.tabs {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpsc11x5/).