# Div isn't in correct position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spectrumjs

I'm using [Spectrum color picker plugin](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/). There are 2 containers. 1 - `.sp-picker-container` and `.sp-palette-container`. The layout of the containers are created with `float`. I don't want that because that isn't the correct way to lay things out. (see [this answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/advantages-of-using-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft-in-css/15177860#15177860).)

I used `display: inline-block` instead, and removed, or more accurately set `float` to `none`. When I do that, the color picker, (the container on the right side) is pushed a bit down.

How can I make it `display: inline-block` and `float: none`, and have the right side container to the top, leveled with the left side containers top?

Relavent code:

```
.sp-picker-container,
.sp-palette-container {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

#### JSFiddle

I tried adding the code snippet, but the problem wouldn't happen in the code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the property `vertical-align:top` to `.sp-picker-container,
.sp-palette-container`:

```
.sp-picker-container,
.sp-palette-container {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

See http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/ for a reference

Comment: Yes, its: `.sp-picker-container, .sp-palette-container { ... vertical-align: top; }`

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what's causing it to not align to the top?

Comment: I'm afraid no :-) but I had the same problem some days ago and this is how I fixed it.