# How can I centre this text vertically in the span?

Tags: html, css

I want to centre some text vertically in a span which contains an SVG Image. Below is a snippet of my code and you can see the text is aligned to the top of the SVG whereas I want it aligned to the centre. How can I do this? I tried using `vertical-align: middle;` but this made no difference.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.bottom-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5%;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
}
.widgets {
  float: left;
  width: 87%;
}
#settings {
  width: 13%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
#settings > span {
  /* Container */
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}
#settings > span > div {
  /* SVG */
  float: left;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}
#settings > span > p {
  /* Text */
  float: left;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-wrapper">
  <div class="widgets">Place Holder</div>
  <div class="widgets" id="settings">
    <span id="setting1">
            <div id="setting1-light">
                <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 30 30" xml:space="preserve" id="settingsLight">
                    <circle id="settingsLight-oval" stroke="rgb(32, 33, 32)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(47, 222, 107)" cx="15" cy="15" r="12.5"></circle>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <p id="setting1-text">Setting1</p>
        </span>
    <span id="setting2">
            <div id="setting2-light">
                <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 30 30" xml:space="preserve" id="settingsLight">
                    <circle id="settingsLight-oval" stroke="rgb(32, 33, 32)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(222,58,62)" cx="15" cy="15" r="12.5"></circle>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <p id="setting2-text">Setting2</p>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to use `vertical-align` like you tried. For that you need to use `display: inline-block`. You can read more about that [here](http://www.matanich.com/2014/05/01/inline-block-for-vertically-aligned-grids/)

Example:

```
#settings > span > div {
  /* SVG */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#settings > span > p {
  /* Text */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbBwoL

Why is better to use inline-block? [Advantages of using display:inline-block vs float:left in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/advantages-of-using-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

Use line-height instead of height:

```
#settings > span > p {
    float: left;
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so it will stay entered even when the screen is resized?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
#settings > span {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    position: relative; /* NEW */
}

#settings > span > p {
    /* float: left; */
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    position: absolute;  /* NEW */
    top: 23%;  /* NEW */
    left: 20%;  /* NEW */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rxzgvc7z/2/)

Comment: In your demo it doesn't seam to be centred? https://i.gyazo.com/deac6f108d73786ddab3cd43bc922062.png

Comment: It's a simple adjustment to the `top` property. I already revised code and demo. Try again.

Comment: It still does't look centre I don't think ([here](https://i.gyazo.com/cfff7df774bdc4f25b2f258eacc6b627.png)). Which part would I change to make it more centre? And would doing it this way auto adjust if the screen was resized? Thanks.

Comment: It looks pretty centered to me. And it's responsive. Adjust the `top` and `left` properties in the demo to adjust the vertical and horizontal alignment, respectively.