# display: inline-block does not produce horizontal result

Tags: html, css

[This fiddle shows my problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/fvrj5by6/)

The output include only 2 yellow boxes, but there could be more. I want the boxes to display horizontally, not vertically as they now display. I have attempted to use `display: inline-block` to accomplish my goal, but to no avail. How can I get the boxes to display horizontally?

Comment: Do you want the elements to be next to each other in the center of the page OR under each other in the center of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `float: left` to `.sticky` (and some margin left or/and right):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lcrysuzy/

Comment: advantages of inline-block over float: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/advantages-of-using-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft-in-css

Answer (score 1):

I was able to horiontally center the elements by adding `float: left;` to `.sticky` and removing `display: inline-block`:

```
.sticky {
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The display:inline-block is not really needed. I have not used `float:` before.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block` for the `div` with `class="element"` and remove `<div class="reminders">` that you put just before the second `<div class="element"`

Comment: I think this is a very good idea because it appears that div "reminders" is not needed. I suspect your answer would produce the same desirable results that @Erik suggested, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to remove elements or make them float, add `display: inline-block` to both parents: `.reminders, .element {display: inline-block}`

Comment: That has the advantage that the boxes are centered like the title area, instead of the boxes starting on the left margin. I like that.