# Arrange inputs into equal length

Tags: html, css, input

I have multiple rows with inputs

```html
<input type="text" style="width: 50px;">
<br>
<input type="text" style="width: 25px;">
<input type="text" style="width: 25px;">
```

Unfortunately the `25+25 != 50` because there is a space between, which varies by each browser.

[image]

Question: How to style the inputs to get `2x25` has equal lenth with `1x50`

Comment: The space is just white space which you have in your code in the form of a new line https://jsfiddle.net/375g0z0x/3/ inputs have default styles and you need to reset them to make them "clean"

Comment: You can put the first input inside a div with a css width: 150px and change his style to width: 100% and for the others, put both in same div and changes their styles to width: 50% respectily.

Comment: just as a note: don't use inline css - it's hard to manage and makes it harder for frameworks (like bootstrap) to apply the css (due to specificity)

Comment: an addition to @Dariel comment - use a container div with percentages on inpit for responsive design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box` on all the input elements and make sure to avoid the white-spacing between the two elements. One way is to have both the `input`s in the same line or the other (preferred and more readable) way is to add a comment in between the two.

```css
.full {
  width: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.half {
  width: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="full">
<br>
<input type="text" class="half"><!--
--><input type="text" class="half">
```

Comment: Another way to have both inputs on the same line is using `float` ;)

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden use `display: inline-block` - float is too crazy to use haha

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs If you think float is crazy, you didn't understand float. Using inline elements and comments to fix the whitespaces is unpredictable when using dynamic content.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden it's behaviour is unpredicatable sometimes, that's why people are more and more using display: inline-block in place of float, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/advantages-of-using-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft-in-css for some advantages :)