# CSS - Inline-block Misalignment

Tags: html, css

On the `second example`, why does the second `div` block starts from the bottom of the first `inline-block` but the `first example` is working as intended?

```css
.working-left {
  background-color: green;
}

.working-right {
  background-color: red;
}

.left-panel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 220px;
}

.right-panel {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
First Example
<div>
  <div class="left-panel working-left">
    Working Left Panel
  </div>
  <div class="right-panel working-right">
    Working Right Panel
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
Second Example
<div>
  <div class="left-panel">
    asd
  </div>
  <div class="right-panel">
    Drumstick boudin fatback hamburger, ground round pig porchetta. Tenderloin short ribs pork prosciutto meatloaf, strip steak ground round. Shoulder jerky biltong, t-bone shankle tri-tip venison boudin prosciutto leberkas turkey pancetta alcatra ham hock pastrami. Tenderloin ground round rump chuck boudin meatball capicola strip steak tail corned beef prosciutto short ribs tongue jerky. Brisket shankle prosciutto meatloaf porchetta jowl biltong cupim flank sirloin beef shoulder pork chop. Landjaeger brisket jowl, cupim buffalo spare ribs swine drumstick shoulder.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because your blocks will take as much width as they need, and will move out of the way to a new line when too large. Try giving them different width and you will see them 'line up' again. You might be looking for `flexbox` instead of `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example it comes down as it don't have enough space to accompany it.

Currently i have added with to ".right-pannel" class, then both will be on the same row.

```css
.working-left {
  background-color: green;
}

.working-right {
  background-color: red;
}

.left-panel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 220px;
}

.right-panel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
First Example
<div>
  <div class="left-panel working-left">
    Working Left Panel
  </div>
  <div class="right-panel working-right">
    Working Right Panel
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
Second Example
<div>
  <div class="left-panel">
    asd
  </div>
  <div class="right-panel">
    Drumstick boudin fatback hamburger, ground round pig porchetta. Tenderloin short ribs pork prosciutto meatloaf, strip steak ground round. Shoulder jerky biltong, t-bone shankle tri-tip venison boudin prosciutto leberkas turkey pancetta alcatra ham hock pastrami. Tenderloin ground round rump chuck boudin meatball capicola strip steak tail corned beef prosciutto short ribs tongue jerky. Brisket shankle prosciutto meatloaf porchetta jowl biltong cupim flank sirloin beef shoulder pork chop. Landjaeger brisket jowl, cupim buffalo spare ribs swine drumstick shoulder.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you got to restrict the width of "*right-panel"* in order to align it just beside the "*left-panel*" (making use of "display: inline-block" is to give widths etc. unlike "display: inline")

Answer (score 0):

You set up a width for the left panel which is fine but it means you should set up a width for the other one to make them aligned because the second right panel has a lot of text so it takes all the space. If you reduce the text to one word on the second right panel you will get the same as the first example. Please check the following link for details : [Display inline-block vs float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/advantages-of-using-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the width property for the `right-panel` too, otherwise it'll take as much as width for it to fit in the view. Either set width using `%` property(like for `right-panel` 20% and say 70% for `left-panel`) or set width precisely using `px` (like `200px` for `right-panel`and `400px` for `left-panel`). Use as per your convenience.