# Separating 2 input tags, displayed side by side using `float: left`

Tags: html, css, input

I have used this **float: left** on the first div so that both the labels and input tags are displayed side by side. But because of that now there is no space between the two. I have tried margin and padding both, but wasn't able to separate them.

```
<div style="float:left;">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input style="height: 34px; width: 310px;" type="text" name="title">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name<label style="color: red;">*</label></label>
            <input style="height: 34px; width: 310px;" type="text" name="name" required>
        </div><br>
```

Is there any other way I can make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally will work to simply pad the one side of your wrapping divs. Here's a cleaned up code example:

```css
.left {
  float: left;
}
input {
  height: 34px;
  width: 150px;
}
.req {
  color: red;
}
.input-wrapper {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper left">
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" />
</div>
<div class="input-wrapper left">
  <label for="name">Name<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="name" required />
</div>
```

I made the width of the input fields smaller just to illustrate that they do indeed stack along side each other in this format, while creating the necessary separation.

Also, note that you shouldn't nest a label within a label. If you want to include something like a required filed notation, use something like a span, instead. Either that or add a "required" class to that label, and style the `::after` pseudo class selector.

Comment: Points noted. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A better way to achieve the desired result would be to use "display:inline-block" on each div, rather than using 'float'.

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input style="height: 34px; width: 310px;" type="text" name="title">
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <label for="name">Name<label style="color: red;">*</label></label>
        <input style="height: 34px; width: 310px;" type="text" name="name" required>
    </div><br>
```

You can find more information about using inline-blocks vs floats here: 
 [Advantages of using display:inline-block vs float:left in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/advantages-of-using-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft-in-css)