# HTML/CSS about position: relative

Tags: html, css

I used  Visual Studio Code  and opened with live server.
I noticed 'position: relative' of box_1's '#red' is not working
How do you make it work?

---

edit image link of expecting result

---

also tried with unique ids 
ex) red_1, orange_1, yellow_1 
if possible can you tell me the reason it's not working 
Thinking about conflict between ralative and float but I'm not sure

---

HTML

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W4Gj.png)

[expecting_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNaHL.png)

```css
.box_1{  
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float: left; 
    }
    
.box_2{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
   
.box_3{ 
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }

#red{
     background-color: red;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     position: relative;        
   }

#orange{
     background-color: orange;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     position: relative;
   }

#yellow{
     background-color: yellow;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     position: relative;
   }
html
```

```html
<div class="box_1" id="red"></div>
<div class="box_1" id="orange"></div>
<div class="box_1" id="yellow"></div>

<div class="box_2" id="red">
    <div class="box_2" id="orange">
        <div class="box_2" id="yellow">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box_3" id="red"></div>
<div class="box_3" id="orange"></div>
<div class="box_3" id="yellow"></div>
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Did you try `z-index: 1`

Comment: what is your expected behavior? Also `id` should be unique. In your HTML you have used many times same `id`

Comment: Non-unique ids work sometimes but it can give unexpected results across browsers in some cases, so always use unique IDs to rule this out and then see if you still face the issue

Comment: @AnikethMalyala I edit/ image link for the expecting result. sorry..

Comment: @JS_INF I also used z-index but not what I was expecting...

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I edit the link of expecting result. sorry..

Comment: @DeepakKamat thanks I'll try with unique ids. :)

Comment: @na08 given my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video will explain your issue why float doesn't take a block space.
https://youtu.be/UAWLXYUGqpc

And the reason is the floated item is taken out from the flow.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/In_Flow_and_Out_of_Flow#taking_an_item_out_of_flow

Try this example to see how float is working.

```
<style>
.float_div{  
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: blue;
      float: right;
    }
    
.box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 30%;
}
   
</style>
<html>
    <div class="float_div"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</html>
```

Just fyi, I'd not recommend to use float to layout divs.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15177860

Comment: THANK YOU. Your answer helped me a lot! I feel so much better now...!

Answer (score 0):

just add another `<div class="box_1" id="red"></div>` to the top:

```css
.box_1{  
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float: left; 
    }
    
.box_2{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
   
.box_3{ 
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }

#red{
     background-color: red;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     position: relative;        
   }

#orange{
     background-color: orange;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     position: relative;
   }

#yellow{
     background-color: yellow;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     position: relative;
   }
```

```html
<div class="box_1" id="red"></div>
<div class="box_1" id="red"></div>
<div class="box_1" id="orange"></div>
<div class="box_1" id="yellow"></div>

<div class="box_2" id="red">
    <div class="box_2" id="orange">
        <div class="box_2" id="yellow">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box_3" id="red"></div>
<div class="box_3" id="orange"></div>
<div class="box_3" id="yellow"></div>
```

or better rewrite it to a valid HTML:

```css
.box_1{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float: left; 
    }
    
.box_2{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
   
.box_3{ 
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }

.red{
     background-color: red;
   }

.orange{
     background-color: orange;
   }

.yellow{
     background-color: yellow;
   }

.box_2,
.box_2 *
{
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_1 red"></div>
<div class="box_1 red"></div>
<div class="box_1 orange"></div>
<div class="box_1 yellow"></div>
    <div class="box_2 orange">
        <div class="box_2 yellow">
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="box_3 red"></div>
<div class="box_3 orange"></div>
<div class="box_3 yellow"></div>
```

Comment: sorry to bother not putting the expecting result. I edited the link of image.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

To Achieve your desired result, you have to given the margin for the first red box, so that next relative red box will place in that and will get the desired result.

```
.box_1#red {
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

```css
.box_1{  
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float:left;
    }
 .box_1#red {
      margin-left:100px;
 }
    
.box_2{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    
.box_3{ 
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      
    }

#red{
     background-color: red;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     position: relative;        
   }

#orange{
     background-color: orange;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     position: relative;
   }

#yellow{
     background-color: yellow;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     position: relative;
   }
```

```html
<div class="box_1" id="red"></div>
<div class="box_1" id="orange"></div>
<div class="box_1" id="yellow"></div>

<div class="box_2" id="red">
    <div class="box_2" id="orange">
        <div class="box_2" id="yellow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
      

<div class="box_3" id="red"></div>
<div class="box_3" id="orange"></div>
<div class="box_3" id="yellow"></div>
```