# CSS circles and lines - connectors

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create some lines and circles that connect themselves with each other.

Here is [my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/v9Vqe/) but I am only able to connect the first circle to the first line, however I want to have several displayed horizontally.

Code from fiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
.flow {
    height: 5em;
    left: -0.3em;   
}

.flow div:first-child {
    left: 0em;  
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(50, 160, 45, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(50, 160, 45, 0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(50, 160, 45, 0.75);
    position: relative;
    left:inherit;
}

.line {
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    height: 0.5em;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1.0em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(50, 160, 45, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(50, 160, 45, 0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(50, 160, 45, 0.75);
    left:inherit;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flow">
       <div id="circle1" class="circle"></div>
       <div class="line"> </div>
       <div id="circle1" class="circle"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You may also go with somerhing like this : http://jsfiddle.net/dq7pf/11/

Comment: @NicoO Nice but I need to have lines with a length attribute, and separated from circles.

Comment: I can not edit edit anymore for the next hours. Will get back to this if there is no answer till then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the spaces between your `circle` and `line` elements.

To solve it, you can use one of the following:

- Use floating. Downside: floating converts elements to blocks, so it breaks the vertical aligning of inline-blocks.
- Use `font-size: 0`. Downside: it breaks lengths with `em` units.
- Use `text-space-collapse: trim-inner`. Downside: is a draft, no browser support.
- Wrap the spaces in html comments.

<sup>(Also see [Ignore whitespace in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628050/ignore-whitespace-in-html))</sup>

In your case, the last one is the best:

```
<div class="flow"><!--
    --><div class="circle"></div><!--
    --><div class="line"></div><!--
--></div>
```

You can see it in action in this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9Vqe/3/).

<sub>(Note I also added `white-space: nowrap` to avoid breaking lines, and`z-index:1` to show circles above lines)</sub>

Comment: It works great !! But do I really need to go that way? If I switch to pixels can I use your second approach? (plus 1 meanwhile :), nice effort).

Comment: @user2779312 Yes, you can switch to pixels (or any unit non dependent to font-size), or you can reset it with `.circle,.line {font-size: 16px}` [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9Vqe/4/)