# Line break before last inline div in the line (div overflow)

Tags: html, css, layout

If four inline-block divs of 25% width are put into a container div - the last one always ends up on the next line. If you set the width to 24% - the divs would stay in line, as intended. I tested in latest Chrome

Like here - http://jsfiddle.net/n3aa3/

```
<div id="c">
    <div class="i">hello
    </div>
    <div class="i">i
    </div>
    <div class="i">love
    </div>
    <div class="i">u
    </div>
</div>

#c{
    background-color:purple;
    height:30px;
    padding:10px;
}
.i{
    border:1px solid white;
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:25%;
}
```

Why? Is the margin between them (who did that margin?) is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `inline-block` are treated like `inline` elements (*treated like text in simple words*), The consecutive `whitespace` or `line break`s among the `inline-block` elements in your `html` markup will be considered as a single whitespace.

You can remove the line breaks in markup to remove the whitespace between `inline-block` elements.

In your case though, the `border` also adds to the effective size of the element. You can change this behavior of [default box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Box_model)  by applying [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n3aa3/8/)

Comment: >Tilwin you are totally right but i loose the identation in markup! this is really strange, maybe we can say ask broswer to ignore \r\n's?

Comment: @user3616003 if ancient browser support is not an issue, instead of using `inline-block`, you can use [css3 flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), by simply applying `display:flex` to parent element like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n3aa3/10/).

Answer (score 1):

You want to add:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

By default on most browsers, the `width` and `height` refer to the "contents" of a block, i.e. without padding or border. So when you say `width: 25%`, that means the total width is actually 25% + the padding + the border.

Also, you need to remove the white space between the end of a div and the start of another one, as it adds space between them.

Comment: jcaron that works! But i had to delete all whitespace between divs.. and lost all identation ([js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3aa3/7/)). Is there some hack to do this? using ::before and ::after?!

Comment: There's some discussion about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628050/ignore-whitespace-in-html The situation doesn't seem to have changed much, the best option seems to be `font-size: 0px` on the outer `div` (which means you need to reset it in inner elements).

Answer (score 1):

To continue Tilwin idea, you can see [here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) several techniques to remove that spacing, i've used "parent `font-size:0` child retablish font-size" technique, you can see updated version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n3aa3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Borders are added to the total width:

```
.i{
    border:1px solid white;// <--This is your issue
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:25%;
}
```

You can nest a div to fix this:

```
<div id="c">
    <div class="i"><div>hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="i"><div>i</div>
    </div>
</div>

.i{

        display:inline-block;
        height:20px;
        width:25%;
}
.i div {
     border:1px solid white;
}
```

Also as noted by others, whitespace in inline elements effects the layout as well.
Perhaps the best option would be to ditch inline-block and use floats instead:

```
<div id="c">
    <div class="i"><div>hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="i"><div>i</div>
    </div>
</div>

#c {
       overflow:hidden;
       background-color:purple;
       height:30px;
       padding:10px;
}


.i{
     float:left;
     height:20px;
     width:25%;
}
.i div {
     border:1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `float:left` in place of `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

your `.i` class must have

```
.i{
    border:1px solid white;

    height:20px;
    width:25%; 
    float:left;/* <-- this*/
    box-sizing:border-box;/* <-- this*/


}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/n3aa3/6/

i don't understand why you are using `display:inline-block` though

Comment: because `float`s have side effects, if you use `float` then you'll have to `clear` fix it.

Comment: inline-block is good and self-declarative property. float is bad

Comment: @TilwinJoy inline-block also have side-effects :) everything has.. it depends on what you need.

Comment: @vlrprbttst `inline-block` plays pretty straight forward… float will have plenty of side effects if you don't know how exactly it works in different situations… my favorite is `flex`, which also has slight drawback of browser support… well can't except more than that from web world :D