# Can't arrange two Bootstrap's buttons inline within a footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to make a footer with the two [buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) by using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) library. Every button should be 50% width, but instead of be placed in same line, second button moved to new line. If I change width of the buttons to 49% everything works. 
I've added `box-sizing: border-box;` but it didn't help.

There's my html code:

```css
.footer{
    background-color: lime;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 10vh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer > button{
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 border-radius: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Close</button>
</div>
```

My codepen: http://codepen.io/anatoly314/pen/VezEOJ

**Update**: actually my question is part of well known problem which has much broader covering in this topic: [Ignore whitespace in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628050/ignore-whitespace-in-html), I won't close it because people already answered but advice you to look for solution in a topic mentioned above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore whitespace in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628050/ignore-whitespace-in-html)

Comment: Have you just voted to close your own question? :D

Comment: Actually yes, see my update. I won't delete my question because I coldn't imagine that it related to white spaces so I guess there're another people with same. So if somebody will come here with the same issue he will be redirected to right topic.

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap you have to use columns, you can read about it in their documentation.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So 100% width is md-12, then you can play with that number, 6 / 6 is two columns of 50% each in a row.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `display: inline-block` is white space dependent and the elements won't stick on one line. Edit your `html` and remove the white space between buttons to fix it:

```
<div class="footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Close</button>
</div>
```

Or you can use `html` comment:

```
<div class="footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button><!--
    --><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change your HTML codes to the following:

```
<div class="footer">
    <button type="button" class="col-sm-6 btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="col-sm-6 btn btn-default btn-lg">Close</button>
</div>
```

you can use bootstrap classes helping you in size for the buttons also not only div elements

Answer (score 1):

You can find a working [codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VezVvZ). I suggest you to take a look at the [Bootsrap's Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

```css
.footer {
  background-color: lime;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 10vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer > .row {
  margin: 0;
}

.footer > .row > div {
  margin: 0;
}

.footer button {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Save</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```