# how to avoid empty line in pre formatting text

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="divright">
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
</div>
```

css

```
#divright{
    white-space:pre;
}
```

There is an extra empty line at he top of `divright`content, because of `white-space:pre` formatting.

How can I avoid this empty line.

I tried css `display:none` - doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the HTML, simply delete it:

```
<div id="divright">lorem ipsum
```

If you know, that there will always be a newline and you know the line height, pull the whole element one line higher:

```
#divright {
  margin-top: -20px; /* -1 x current line-height */
}
```

The `white-space-collapse` property of CSS4 will last a bit, until it is ready to save us here.

For `contenteditable` elements, you could listen to [the `input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) and trim away the leading line break with Javascript every time a user tries to add it.

Comment: thanks but I need later to make `divright` contenteditable, so in this case cursor is hidden.

Comment: There is a property in the pipe called `white-space-collapse`, but it won't hit browsers near you until we both look forward to retirement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2629446/113195

Answer (score 0):

just delete the actuall space before the first line

```
<div id="divright">lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: can I delete it using javascript ?

Comment: yes, try getting  the div by id,  calling trimleft in its inner html.
    var newtext= document.getElementById("divright").innerHTML;
    newtext= newdiv.trimLeft();
    document.getElementById("divright").innerHTML = "newtext";

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use :

```
#divright{
    white-space:normal;
}
```

or

```
#divright{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

It should delete this empty line. To more help look at [W3C-Css Tutorial.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: thanks, but there is a reason to keep `white-space:pre`