# Horizontally align set of divs from center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, inline

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeleniy/23m8cwxr/)

```
see jsfiddle
```

Could anyone say why i see 3 elements per row. It seems that there should be 4 because `width` is 25%. And how to fix it? And maybe someone knows how to implement such a thing with bootstrap columns?

I am trying to align from center an unknown amount of `div`s..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect you're seeing is due to the fact that HTML lays out inline-blocks (indeed all inline elements) with any amount of white-space between them recognized as a single space character with a width given by the font-size and family of the inline context.

So even though each inline-block is precisely 25% of its container's width, the spaces between them force the total width of 4 of them together to exceed 100% of the container's width, so the 4th one drops to the next line.

This is the bane of using inline-blocks for layout purposes. There are some suggestions for how to deal with this here: 
[Ignore whitespace in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628050/ignore-whitespace-in-html). Highlights include:

- Setting the font-size of the container to 0, then resetting it on the children to what it needs to be.
- Keeping all the child elements in one line of text  (line-breaks are read as white-space) with no space between them. Note: if you're using a back- or font-end templating system, there may be tools to support this so that your source code has line breaks, but what's sent or rendered in the browser does not.
- Use of HTML comments to exclude the line-breaks and tabs/spaces that you leave between between inline-blocks in your source code (inelegant and hard to maintain).

Some of the other answers to that question suggest techniques where something other than inline-blocks are used to handle the layout, e.g. `float` and `flex`. Those are fine, too, however there are certain aspects of inline-blocks that may make it worth the effort to get them to work, namely:

- You can use `vertical-align` property to control vertical alignment (advantage over floats)
- Items of variable height will appear predictably next to each other (advantage over float)
- The width of each element may be left to determine the spacing between each (advantage over flex)

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the breaks between the `<div>`'s which cause space because of the `inline-block` attribute. Try the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div>Q</div><div>W</div><div>E</div><div>R</div>
</div>
```

Then, you will have four `<div>`'s in a row without spaces in between.

Alternatively, you could reduce the font size of the surrounding `<div>` to zero:

```
.row {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0px;
}
.row > div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #EEE;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `inline-block` do a float:

```
.row > div {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    background-color: #EEE;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

If you want to keep elements centered, just apply a negative margin:

```
margin: 0 0 0 -4px;
```

Comment: No, in that case last row not aligned the from center, but from the left

Comment: Updated my answer.