# Extra space when embedding PHP on HTML

Tags: php, html

I have this code:

[image]

As you can see I have put the PHP code on the second line, since I don't want to exceed the red line (80 characters).

The problem: the URL is generated like this:

[image]

As you can see there is an extra space between the `=` and `value1`. How to avoid that space?

Comment: Put it all on one line. `<a href='my_file.php?parameter1=<?php echo 'value1' ?>">`

Comment: Did you use tabs or spaces to indent it?

Comment: @blackandorangecat but I don't want to exceed the red line..

Comment: @j08691 I have tried tabs and spaces and the result is the same.

Comment: @ziiweb Well, in order to remove that space you need to put it all on the same line...

Comment: yeah put it on one line,  the spaces you are seeing are from it being on two lines. go past the red bar, its the only way :)

Comment: You need to put at least the `<?php` directly after the `= ` - the `echo` can be on the next line ...

Comment: because scrolling is bad? your coding on a tiny screen? any case, you cant have it both ways

Comment: You can't do that what you exactly want. In HTML, whitespaces are't ignored, and if you put the PHP code in a new line, there will be some whitespaces. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628050/ignore-whitespace-in-html

Comment: An 80 character per line arbitrary limit seems pretty weird. Why are you limiting yourself to this? Furthermore I count 55 characters for you whole opening `a` tag. An actual option to get around this is to put the whole `href` attribute its own line. If you're constrained by your arbitrary character count I'd put each attribute on its own line

Answer (score 1):

Never a good practice to split a string. If you don't want to exceed the limit, probably best thing to do is to move the whole string to the next line.

```
<a href=
  "my_file.php?parameter1=<?php echo 'value1';?>">
```

You could also try using the php short tags `<??>` instead of the whole `<?php ?>`.

Another option would be to output the whole line with php like this (with the string concat `.`):

```
<?php echo "<a href='my_file.php?parameter1=".
   'value1'."'>"; ?>
```