# What is the reason of the space below the inline span element?

Tags: html, css, inline

I have been trying to do something and just realized that there is a space under the span element for no reason.
It is easy to remove the space so I am not asking how to remove it. 
I searched google but couldn't find any reason.

Can you please tell me which CSS property causes this or any other reason?

Here is also a codepen link: https://codepen.io/kavramkurdu/pen/qBWzaEQ

The following example shows the space what I exactly search for:

here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot-space-below-span-element]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

span,
a {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span>span element (gy)</span>
<div></div>
<a href="">anchor element (gy)</a>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I see no space anywhere, but whenever you mix inline and block elements like that, you're going to invite odd behaviors. Better to wrap your inline elements in block elements.

Comment: if you reset you inline boxes into inline-block boxes, then the gap goes the boxes have a formatting context (roughly :it can be sized) and bg-color is drawn instead only highlighting the text. If you have any doubt or d noyt understand: 1)  select your text : all the green is gone  - 2) reset display:inline-block to a and span, select the text .. not all the green goes and is exactly the size of your gap when inline : codepen to test selecting text with box setting  inline/inline-block

Comment: Heretic Monkey, if you please look a little closer you can see there is some white space at the bottom of inline elements ( a and span ) right before div elements.

Comment: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oNvrYJw here is the codepen, highlighting text / formatting context are the two keywords.

Comment: @Muhammed https://i.stack.imgur.com/auZPS.png I see no gap in there. I looked as close as I could.

Comment: I added a more approriate duplicate

Comment: @Heretic Monkey , I have just added a screenshot.

Comment: also added another one not directly related but to get more details about line-height, content-area, etc

Comment: @Muhammed So obviously we're using different browsers; perhaps it would be a good idea to mention which browser you're using.

Comment: @HereticMonkey all depend on the default font (set by the browser), this space is closely related to the content area and its calculation is based on the font properties and it may or may not exist for some users

Comment: @HereticMonkey also about *but whenever you mix inline and block elements like that, you're going to invite odd behaviors* --> there will be no odd behavior because when doing such mix the inline elements will first get enclosed within anonymous block element and such behavior is pretty well defined in the Spec: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54627511/8620333